# How can optimize my process for reviewing face recognition in MacOS Photos?

Tags: macos, photos.app

Mac's photos app can show each person's faces:

1. click "people"
2. double-click one person's cover photo
3. click "faces"

It's annoying to click "faces" when I want to review the face-recognition results for everyone.

Is it possible to eliminate the step 3 and inevitable back click   To repeat step 2?